# JavaScript: Accessing ArrayElement by index of other Array Element? array[array[0]] returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make function which accepts 7 digit code (at minimum) and then loads images/elements of character thus creating a character from code.

I wrote this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var skins = [];
skins["w"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/base.png";

var eyes = [];
eyes["b"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/eyes/blue.png";
eyes["g"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/eyes/green.png";
eyes["r"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/eyes/red.png";

var hair = [];
hair["b"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/hair/black.png";
hair["w"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/hair/blond.png";
hair["s"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/hair/brown.png";

var mouth = [];
mouth["h"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/mouth/happy.png";

var pants = [];
pants["s"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/pants/shorts.png";

var shoes = [];
shoes["b"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/shoes/black.png";

var torso = [];
torso["s"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/torso/shirt.png"

function LoadChar(code){
var data = code.split(/(?=[a-z])/i);
var skins = [skins[data[0]], eyes[data[1]], hair[data[2]], mouth[data[3]], pants[data[4]], shoes[data[5]], torso[data[6]]];

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = skins.toString();
}
</script>
<div id="out"></div>
```

However, when I call LoadChar("wgbhsbs");

It thorws me "Cannot read property 'w' of undefined"

I am still new to Arrays in JS, so I am sure I am making some simple Syntax error or doing something a bit wrong.

So what this does is:

1) Accepts code and splits it into 7 elements (always 7, nothing else) stores it in "data" variable as array.
2) Builds "skins" array by loading: skin[number from code] and same for other elements.
3) For testing purposes I am trying to output skins array, but it stops at step 2.

Is there any explanation to this?

Comment: You're creating properties to the arrays, not indices.

Comment: arrays should not use letters or strings as keys.

Comment: Except urls, yes it's same.

Comment: Your real issue is that you define `skins` twice, once outside the function, and then a local variable inside the function with the same name, that doesn't have a `w` property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are recreating the previously defined `skins` variable.

Use a different name for the variable inside the function, and you'll be fine.

```js
var skins = [];
skins["w"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/base.png";

var eyes = [];
eyes["b"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/eyes/blue.png";
eyes["g"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/eyes/green.png";
eyes["r"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/eyes/red.png";

var hair = [];
hair["b"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/hair/black.png";
hair["w"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/hair/blond.png";
hair["s"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/hair/brown.png";

var mouth = [];
mouth["h"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/mouth/happy.png";

var pants = [];
pants["s"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/pants/shorts.png";

var shoes = [];
shoes["b"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/shoes/black.png";

var torso = [];
torso["s"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/torso/shirt.png"

function LoadChar(code){
  var data = code.split(/(?=[a-z])/i);
  var other_variable = [skins[data[0]], eyes[data[1]], hair[data[2]], mouth[data[3]],   pants[data[4]], shoes[data[5]], torso[data[6]]];

  alert(other_variable.toString());
}
LoadChar("wgbhsbs");
```

Comment: Well, that solved all the problems. 
I knew it's something small, I need to be a bit more careful with namings. Didn't even notice naming two variables same names. Thank you.

Comment: Also do I need to change all array elements to {}  as mentioned in other answers?

Comment: @arleitiss - You don't **need** to... but you **should**

Answer (score 1):

You're defining properties of an object. Not an array.

Change

```
var skins = [];
skins["w"] = "http://example.com/char_elements/base.png";
```

to

```
var skins = {};
skins.w = "http://example.com/char_elements/base.png";
```

Also you're redefining `skins` inside your LoadChar function as LcSalazar pointed out.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/zyt2fyg3/)**

Comment: Although more appropriate, it won't make any difference. Arrays are object and can have properties indexed by strings just like any other object.

Comment: So do I access skins/eyes/hair elements like skins.data[0] is that right?

Comment: @arleitiss: No, you'd still access as `skins["w"]`

Comment: @arleitiss check the Fiddle

Comment: @Jonathan Checked, modified my code now. Thanks for contributing to solution.